# Setting variable inside onDataChange in Firebase (singleValue Listener)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is just an example of what my code is like. Right now, if I print out the userName variable inside onDataChange, it works fine. But if I try printing userName outside, after the listener, it will print 'null'. How would I be able to store a variable, with the data I want, inside onDataChange()?

```
public class FireBaseTest extends .... {

    String userName;

    ...

    mDatabase.child("Users").child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                    new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            // Get user value
                            userName = dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue(String.class);
                            System.out.println(userName); //Not null
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    });


    ...

    System.out.println(userName); //Null
```

EDIT/UPDATE: 
So before I had a process that would take the value that was being listened and do something with it. I just made some adjustments to that process and added it in the onDataChanged method just to end my suffering. Even though it's not entirely satisfying, it worked. Thank you to all who answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Listeners in Firebase are asynchronous, so you can not set a variable like that. You should pass a callback function in the function where you have declared your listener.

This callback function will then take the result from firebase call and do further processing on it.

```
public void doSomething(@NotNull final Callback callback) {

    final Query query = mDatabase.child(FirebaseConstants.TARGET);

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String userName = dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue(String.class);
            callback.OnComplete(userName);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That's interesting. I've never written a callback function before so hopefully this works. I just have trouble figuring out what class I have to import since there are so many for Callback.

Comment: @SaltySea You have to declare a callback function in an interface and pass this interface as an argument.

Comment: Hi. Isn't this the same as adding whatever there is to be done in the function itself. I am about to read into callbacks so sorry if it's a stupid question.

Comment: @Amit0191 yes, you can write everything down in onDataChange but I prefer it like this, it's much cleaner.

Comment: Is there anyway to set a "onCompletion" listener if you will to onDataChange or on addValueEvents?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase event listeners are excuted Asynchrounosly, meaning, it runs in background and when it's done, it notifies you using the callback you provided in your case the `ValueEventListener` and calls one or more of it's methods `onDataChanged` or `onCancelled`.

That said, printing the `userName` variable might show a value and might not, depending on whether the callback was triggered before printing it or not.

So, it's a pretty natural behaviour as code excutes one line at a time.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I've often found tricky with Firebase. The only real solutions I could suggest would be to make sure that any code where you need to access the Firebase variables is either:

1) Inside the onDataChange method.

2) Only called/accessed once the addListenerForSingleValueEvent onDataChange method has completed.

Comment: How do you know that it has completed?

Comment: Yeah... how do you know that it has completed? there are no onCompleteListeners()... I was thinking of using an Observer Pattern for it, but still havent got very far