# How to set global var from onDataChange function

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm using firebase in my project and i'm trying to figure out how to fix the next issue for few hours already without success,
I have the next code:

```
// gameIDperm is set as 0 as default
    public void GenerateID(){
            ref2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.hasChild(gameIDperm))
                    {
                        gameIDperm = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(gameIDperm)+1); 
                        Log.d("ID XXXX" , gameIDperm); // Here it says the right number
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
            Log.d("ID YYYYYYYY" , gameIDperm); // Here it says gameIDperm is 0 again

        }
```

How can i make the variable being saved in the current function and not being reset again to default?

Hope you can help!

Comment: What do you mean reset again to default? When is this happening and what do you want exactly? If this is a local field then the only way this value will reset to default is if the context of where it is has been destroyed.

Comment: @riadrifai , i've set it as 0 in the onCreate , in the Log.d that is in the "if" it says the right number , but after the fucntion is done its 0 again

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209823/setting-variable-inside-ondatachange-in-firebase-singlevalue-listener

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen , I've tried the first answer,  why does it says "Cannot resolve method 'OnComplete'

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen which callback should i import?

Comment: `Callback` is just a interface/class here that you define that has a single method `OnComplete` (in the linked example) that does the work you want after the data is loaded.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how do i retrieve later the String from this class?

Answer (score 1):

The code inside of the firebase listener is a callback, it will be called at some point in the future but it is not specified when that will happen.

So what happens is:

1. You call `ref2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(..)`
2. You execute `Log.d("ID YYYYYYYY" , gameIDperm);`, at this point the variable has not been changed yet.
3. Firebase invokes `onDataChange(..)` at a later date, changing the variable.
4. You execute `Log.d("ID XXXX" , gameIDperm);`

In such an asynchronous execution you cannot rely on the order of the code to tell you when things get executed.

In addition you are using the variable `gameIDperm` to look up a child of the firebase reference, then rewriting that variable with the contents. This is probably not correct.

Comment: Than how should i do it?