# want to use onDataChange variable data below the event listener

Tags: android, database, firebase

I have this

```
 mDatabase.child(sharedPrefs.getString("Person_id","error")).child("pago").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                pago = Integer.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                Log.e("pagoono",""+pago);



            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        Log.e("pago",""+pago);
```

I have my database reference to a value , it's 0 or 1 , and i need to use that value after i close the `ValueEventListener`, so, im getting the value inside the `onDataChange` but i can't access that value.I'm trying to access that value in this `Log.e("pago",""+pago)`

Comment: try to watch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209823/setting-variable-inside-ondatachange-in-firebase-singlevalue-listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply use that value outside `onDataChange()` method because this method is called asynchronous. This means that is called before you are getting the data from the database. The simplest way would be to use that value only inside the `onDataChange()` or a more complex way would be to dive into asynchronous world and use that value outside. For that, please see my answer from this post: [How To Get Value Async In Outside Method onDataChange()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange).